# Does X509Certificate2(path, pw, MachineKeySet) only work for admin users?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509, x509certificate2

I am using X509Certificate2 to store a private key in the local machine registry store rather than the current user store. Does the user of my application need to have admin privileges on the machine in order for this to work, or will this work with a standard account? This is being used in a winforms desktop application.

Here is my code:

```
m_cert = new X509Certificate2( path, 
  password, 
  X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet );
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct. Only local admins have permissions to install certificates in Local Machine store.